# How do I resolve message "There was an error. Please try again" when accepting Google Account Transfer request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-identity

We have just set up a Google Cloud Identity domain, and have a number of users who already have consumer Google accounts using their corporate email addresses.

I've invited several of them to transfer their account to our domain - most have succeeded, but two receive a message when clicking through the process to accept the transfer request.

A pop up appears at the bottom of the screen saying

```
There was an error. Please try again'.
```

No further information is given

Does anyone know the cause and/or resolution to this error

Update: My colleagues tried accepting the request a week or so later, and strangely it worked OK. IF anyone else experiences this, it looks like it was a transient issue with transferring accounts into Organisational control.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [conflicting accounts](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7062710?hl=en&ref_topic=7558419). This could happen when users sign up for free Google services before their organization signs up for a managed Google Account. If this is the case, there is [Transfer tool for unmanaged users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6178640).

If info above doesn't help you might want to check if logs contains more details about the error. In [Admin console logs](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9281640?hl=en), or maybe in [Google Cloud Project audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/audit-logging).

Comment: Thanks for the response - strangely this resolved itself yesterday when my colleagues re-tried accepting the invite. It failed several times the week before, so I'm presuming it was a transient error.